# SQL datediff = N in where does not work

Tags: sql-server, datediff

Why doesn't the second select return results? It is the same query but looks like DATEDIFF does not work in where clause.

```
SELECT proposedend, DATEDIFF(day,ProposedEnd, GETDATE())
FROM Campaign
WHERE CampaignId = '2AB915AF-48CD-E431-BEE2-4EF3FC563A54'
```

[image: Query Result]

```
SELECT C.CampaignId, 'test@test.test' 
FROM Campaign C
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,ProposedEnd, GETDATE()) = 1 AND C.TypeCode = 2
```

Comment: Are you sure this row have `TypeCode = 2`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the SQL code itself. There must be an anomaly with the data in your tables.

Comment: Try to comment out second condition and check again

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 cases why the result is not coming:

Case 1:

If `DATEDIFF(day,ProposedEnd, GETDATE()) = 1` is **true** 
then `C.TypeCode = 2` is **false** since you have used and operator thats why you are not getting output.

Case 2:

`C.TypeCode = 2` is **true** but `DATEDIFF(day,ProposedEnd, GETDATE()) = 1` is **false** because your `proposedend` date is above 1 day or currentdate so the condition will always be false in that case.

Comment: Case 2 can't really be the case because it shows 1 in the screenshot.